# React Native: How to pass props in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my React Native application, I am using [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/) and have a class component using [`react-native-webview`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview):

```
<WebView source={{ uri: this.props.url }} />
```

This is implemented in a StackNavigator like so:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Viewer" component={WebViewScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

How can I used [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass a `url` prop to the `WebViewScreen` component?

Looking at [the react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props), it mentions an alternative:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
  {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={someData} />}
</Stack.Screen>
```

but with caveats, so I would like to try to use context. Ideally, I would be able to push to the stack and point the `WebViewScreen` to any url:

```
this.props.navigation.push('Viewer', {
    route: 'https://www.example.com'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about the value changing on a navigation action to a screen where your Webview lives, you can simply access the data you passed on navigation via the `route` prop:

```
const route = this.props.route.params?.route ?? 'default url';

<WebView source={{ uri: route }} />
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#no-more-getparam

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! It's not using context, but is actually probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add the provider and get the value in your component.

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();

<MyContext.Provider value={{url: '/somethig'}}>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Viewer" component={WebViewScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</MyContext.Provider>
```

In your `HomeScreen` use the hooks to get your value:

```
const value = useContext(MyContext);
```

Comment: Actually I rewrote it from a function component to a class component thinking I needed to for access to props, state and lifecycle etc... I see there are workarounds, but I was also having trouble with the context always saying `MyContext` was undefined inside the component.

Comment: you have to import your `MyContext` to be able to use it inside another component